# Lubuntu won't boot to GUI

Tags: boot

I just installed Lubuntu 14.04.5 onto an old Dell Inspiron mini using LVM.
It only boots to command line - tried sudo startx, init 5 but to no effect. Any ideas how to get GUI up? P.S. I'm a linux newbie

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo service lightdm restart`?

Comment: I get a blank screen/flashing cursor.